# change color of pseudo-element based on class name Javascript

Tags: javascript, css

I have a pseudo-element (markers) whose color should change color when a particular class is loaded.

html -

```
<ol>
    <li>
       ::marker
       <span class='be_blue'> First </span>
    </li>
</ol>
```

If the class name='be_blue' then the marker should also be blue else it should remain black.
This has to be done from Javascript

```
const markerColor = document.getElementByClassName('be_blue')
```

After getting element what should I do?

Comment: It will be easier if you add that class to `li`

Comment: if I add class how can i filter out the change of color in marker? could you show that in working?

Comment: If you add `be_blue` class to `li` instead of `span` you can easily manage that using css

Comment: class for span is in-built cz it changes dynamically hence I cant change that but any additional classes for li I can manage

Comment: check my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add class to `li` dynamically and add css on it to change marker color

```js
const markerColor = document.getElementsByClassName('be_blue');

for (i = 0; i < markerColor.length; i++) {
  const par = (markerColor[i].parentNode);
  par.classList.add("blue");
}
```

```css
ol li::marker {
  color: black;
}

ol li.blue::marker {
color: blue;
}
```

```html
<ol>
    <li>
       <span class='be_blue'> First </span>
    </li>
    <li>
       <span class='be_blue'> Secomd </span>
    </li>
    <li>
       <span class='be_blue'> Third </span>
    </li>
</ol>
```

Comment: What if I have a list of li? cz the code you've written only for the first li element by using [0]

Comment: In that case loop through each li with a child having class 'be_blue'

Comment: Code Updated as per your query